# Using Expressions to build Array.Contains for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I want to have a variable field in both Where-Contains and Select.  "field_a" is the guy I want to be variable (sometimes I want field_b or _c; they are strings).  The code below properly builds the Select as `Select(x => x.field_a)`.  How do I get the second part of the Where clause to say, `&& targetCodes.Contains(x.field_a)`?  [`db` is a `DbContext`, `itemsArray` is an array of objects that have a string property called `Code`.]

```
    using (var db = dbFactory.CreateInstance())
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(myTable), "x");
        var field = Expression.Property(parameter, "field_a");
        var selector = Expression.Lambda(field, parameter);
        var targetCodes = itemsArray.Select(i => i.Code).ToArray();
        var query = db.myTables
            .Where(x => x.companyId == 1 && targetCodes.Contains(x.field_a))
            .Select((Expression<Func<myTable, string>>)selector);
        return await query.ToArrayAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the most difficult part is to find `MethodInfo` of the `.Contains()` method. You could use `typeof(IEnumerable<string>).GetMethod(...).Where(...)`, but it is usually difficult to do it right for generic method with several overloads. This is a small trick that employs C# compiler to find the correct overload for you by creating temporary expression:

```
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<string>, bool>> containsExpr = (IEnumerable<string> q) => q.Contains((string)null);
var containsMethod = (containsExpr.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;
// containsMethod should resolve to this overload:
// System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<string>(IEnumerable<string>, string)
```

The rest of the program just builds expression by calling appropriate `Expression.XYZ()` methods:

```
var companyIdEquals1 = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(myTable.companyId)),
    Expression.Constant(1));

var targetCodesContains = Expression.Call(
    containsMethod,
    Expression.Constant(targetCodes),
    field/*reuses expression you already have*/);

var andExpr = Expression.And(companyIdEquals1, targetCodesContains);
var whereExpr = (Expression<Func<myTable, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(andExpr, parameter);

var query = db//.myTables
    .Where(whereExpr)
    .Select((Expression<Func<myTable, string>>)selector);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do that. In this particular case you don't even need to deal with expressions because you could use simply chain `Where` *after* the `Select` (chained `Where` conditions are combined with `&&` in the final query):

```
var query = db.myTables
    .Where(x => x.companyId == 1)
    .Select((Expression<Func<myTable, string>>)selector)
    .Where(v => targetCodes.Contains(v));
```

But to answer your question how to build the expression representing `targetCodes.Contains({field})`, since the actual call (w/o the extension method sugar) you need is `Enumerable.Contains<string>(targetCodes, {field})`, the simplest is to use the following [`Expression.Call`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Call_System_Type_System_String_System_Type___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression___) method overload specifically provided for "calling" static (generic and non generic) methods:

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(
    Type type,
    string methodName,
    Type[] typeArguments,
    params Expression[] arguments
);
```

In your case it could be used like this:

```
var containsCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Contains), new [] { typeof(string) },
    Expression.Constant(targetCodes), field);
```